# How to convert to SVM data format

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

libsvm uses the so called "sparse" format where zero values do not need to be stored. Hence a data with attributes
1 0 2 0
is represented as:
1:1 3:2

I have a dataset, which comes from a sparse matrix. And the format of my dataset is [ row_number  column_num  value]. I paste the my dataset as follows:

```
Row number                column number                                               value
75                                  1                                                0.0079
76                                  1                                                0.0046
37                                  1                                                0.0032
31                                  1                                                0.0028
41                                  1                                                0.0026
64                                  1                                                0.0026
37                                  1                                                0.0025
18                                  1                                                0.0024
94                                  1                                                0.0024
34                                  1                                                0.0023
64                                  1                                                0.0022
40                                  1                                                0.0021
```

My question is how to transfer the my data to the libsvm format, like
+1 18:0.0024  31: 0.0028  34:0.0023  37: 0.0032   37: 0.0025   40: 0.0021  41: 0.0026  ……

Note: +1 mean class 1, if I want to express class 2, I will put +2 in front of the data.
Anyone can give a help and tell me how to realize this by using Matlab! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following example sparse matrix:

```
x = sparse(10,1);
x(3) = 0.04546236;
x(7) = 1.726;
x(8) = 0.63;
```

Then

```
[row, col, val] = find(x);
```

gives

```
row =
     3
     7
     8

val =
    0.0455 %// this appears rounded, but the correct value is stored
    1.7260
    0.6300
```

So:

```
str = strcat(num2str(row), ':', num2str(val), {' '});
str = [str{:}];
str = regexprep(str, ':\s+', ':'); %// remove extra spaces
```

gives the string

```
3:0.045462 7:1.726 8:0.63
```

To add the string `'+1 '` in front, just use standard concatenation:

```
str = ['+1 ' str];
```

Comment: Another question ,How to put +1 or +2 or +3 ...in front of the data?